# PHP object key value comparison of array indexes

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object

I have two arrays where indexes of both arrays are contains objects

```
$array1=array(1) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["aid"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["a_number"]=> string(1) "0" 
    ["id_of"]=> string(1) "1"  
    }
}


$array2=array(3) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "1",
    ["number"]=> string(1) "0" ,
    ["flag"]=> string(1) "1" , 
    ["zflag"]=> string(1) "0" , 
    ["xflag"]=> string(1) "1"  
    } ,
    [1]=> object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "2",
    ["number"]=> string(1) "2" ,
    ["flag"]=> string(1) "2" , 
    ["zflag"]=> string(1) "0" , 
    ["xflag"]=> string(1) "1"  
    },
    [1]=> object(stdClass) (3) {
    ["id"]=> string(1) "3",
    ["number"]=> string(1) "3", 
    ["flag"]=> string(1) "3" , 
    ["zflag"]=> string(1) "0" , 
    ["xflag"]=> string(1) "1"  
    }
}
```

I want to compare between the value of `$id` key in all elements of `$array2` with the value of  `$id_of` each element of `$array1`, if it's not exist then return the element of `$array1`. Below is my code but it doesn't work

```
public function unanswered($array1,$array2){
        if(!(empty($array2))){
            $unanswered_arrays=array();
            foreach($array1 as $b){
                foreach($array2 as $a){
                    if($b->id != $a->id_of){
                        array_push($unanswered_arrays,(object)$b);
                    }
                }
            }
            return $unanswered_arrays;
        }
        return $array1;
    }
```

Comment: What's your desired output? Hard to understand

Comment: @aksen i get null

Comment: Can you show the output you expect as well - this will help to test any solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using your function as `unanswered($array1,$array2)` then replace `$array1` with `$array2` and vice versa in foreach loops or pass `unanswered($array2,$array1)` instead of.

**[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TqN3Y)**