# PHP: Compare key value of objects

Tags: php, arrays, loops, object, foreach

I have two arrays each one contain a set of objects

```
$input = [
    (object)[
        'id'       => 2,
        'number'   => 54523,
        'date'     => '2019-12-17',
        'book_for' => 'tttt',
        'subject'  => 'tttt',
        'content'  => 'ttt',
        'language' => 'Arabic',
        'cpfor'    => 'tt',
        'book_key' => '2WHae',
        'note'     => 'ttt',
        'type'     => 'Internal',
        'pid'      => 2,
        'bookid'   => 2,
        'process'  => 'STA',
    ],
];
```

and the second array is

```
$answers = [
    (object)[
        'aid'             => 1,
        'a_number'        => 0,
        'answer_of'       => 1,
        'answer_date'     => '2019-12-17 00:00:00',
        'answer_for'      => 'xcc',
        'answer_subject'  => 'DSF',
        'answer_content'  => 'FSD',
        'language'        => '',
        'cpfor'           => 'WE',
        'note'            => 'EWWE',
    ],
    (object)[
       'aid'            => 2,
       'a_number'       => 0,
       'answer_of'      => 2,
       'answer_date'    => '2019-12-19 00:00:00',
       'answer_for'     => 'answer for tt',
       'answer_subject' => 'answer for tt',
       'answer_content' => 'answer for tt',
       'language'       => 'Arabic',
       'cpfor'          => 'answer for ttvv',
       'note'           => 'answer for tt',
   ],
];
```

I want looping through and compare the value of `id` key in first `array` with value of `answer_of` key in second `array` if the `id` is not the same `answer_of` then return this object else ignore in other mean if `id` is not exist in second array(`answer_of`) return the object with all key and values else ignore 
i tried the below function but even get those are exist in second array

```
function unanswered2($array1, $array2)
{
    if (!(empty($array2))) {
        $unanswered_arrays = [];
        foreach ($array1 as $b) {
            foreach ($array2 as $a) {
                if ($b->bookid != $a->answer_of) {
                    array_push($unanswered_arrays, (object)$b);
                }
            }
        }

        return $unanswered_arrays;
    }

    return $array1;
}
```

anyone can tell where i have an error or any suggestion

the result is

```
$result=unanswered2($input,$answers);

  $result= [
    (object)[
        'id'       => 2,
        'number'   => 54523,
        'date'     => '2019-12-17',
        'book_for' => 'tttt',
        'subject'  => 'tttt',
        'content'  => 'ttt',
        'language' => 'Arabic',
        'cpfor'    => 'tt',
        'book_key' => '2WHae',
        'note'     => 'ttt',
        'type'     => 'Internal',
        'pid'      => 2,
        'bookid'   => 2,
        'process'  => 'STA',
    ],
];
```

it should ignore it not return

Comment: What is your current output ? What is the expected output ? Would you please use [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead of `var_dump()` so we can copy paste and do tests ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP object key value comparison of array indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386758/php-object-key-value-comparison-of-array-indexes)

Comment: @EzzatHarky please add the expected result too

Comment: @AksenP no i didn't get answer

Comment: @Shibon added result

Comment: So you basically want to remove all entries from `$input` for which no entry exists in `$answers` by some condition?

Comment: @Cid i added the result

Comment: @Yoshi i want remove those are exist in $answer by comparing between $id from $inputs and answer of from $answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest solution is to use [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-filter.php) and a prepared list of *`answer_of`* values (for which you can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.array-column.php)).

Here's an example:

```
function findUnanswered(array $questions, array $answers): array
{
    // use array_column to prepare a list of `answer_of` values
    // *array_flip* them, so we can later use isset for better performance
    $availableAnswers = array_flip(array_column($answers, 'answer_of'));

    // filter all questions 
    return array_filter(
        $questions,

        // by a callback function, that
        static function (object $question) use($availableAnswers): bool {
            //                                            ^ which we *use* from the outer scope
            //                                            |
            // checks if the question id is [not set]* in +
            //                              (* meaning no answer exists)
            return !isset($availableAnswers[$question->id]);
        }
    );
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/ZKlNn

Comment: @EzzatHarky Please use more words to explain "wrong result".

Answer (score 0):

I've read your comment to the prev my answer...

```
function getDiff($ar1, $ar2){

    return array_filter($ar2, function($obj) use ($ar1) { 
        foreach($ar1 as $obj1){
            return $obj1->bookid !== $obj->answer_of;
        } 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
}

print_r(getDiff($input,$answers));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [aid] => 1
            [a_number] => 0
            [answer_of] => 1
            [answer_date] => 2019-12-17 00:00:00
            [answer_for] => xcc
            [answer_subject] => DSF
            [answer_content] => FSD
            [language] => 
            [cpfor] => WE
            [note] => EWWE
        )

)
```

https://3v4l.org/oGQWS

Answer (score 0):

Provided you don't care about the original keys in the answers array.

Input:

```
<?php
$input = [
    (object)[
        'id'       => 2,
        'number'   => 54523,
        'date'     => '2019-12-17',
        'book_for' => 'tttt',
        'subject'  => 'tttt',
        'content'  => 'ttt',
        'language' => 'Arabic',
        'cpfor'    => 'tt',
        'book_key' => '2WHae',
        'note'     => 'ttt',
        'type'     => 'Internal',
        'pid'      => 2,
        'bookid'   => 2,
        'process'  => 'STA',
    ],
];
$answers = [
    (object)[
        'aid'             => 1,
        'a_number'        => 0,
        'answer_of'       => 1,
        'answer_date'     => '2019-12-17 00:00:00',
        'answer_for'      => 'xcc',
        'answer_subject'  => 'DSF',
        'answer_content'  => 'FSD',
        'language'        => '',
        'cpfor'           => 'WE',
        'note'            => 'EWWE',
    ],
    (object)[
       'aid'            => 2,
       'a_number'       => 0,
       'answer_of'      => 2,
       'answer_date'    => '2019-12-19 00:00:00',
       'answer_for'     => 'answer for tt',
       'answer_subject' => 'answer for tt',
       'answer_content' => 'answer for tt',
       'language'       => 'Arabic',
       'cpfor'          => 'answer for ttvv',
       'note'           => 'answer for tt',
   ],
];
```

Method:

```
$unanswered = array_diff_key(
    array_column($answers, null, 'answer_of'),
    array_column($input, null, 'id')
);

var_export($unanswered);
```

Output:

```
array (
    1 => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'aid' => 1,
       'a_number' => 0,
       'answer_of' => 1,
       'answer_date' => '2019-12-17 00:00:00',
       'answer_for' => 'xcc',
       'answer_subject' => 'DSF',
       'answer_content' => 'FSD',
       'language' => '',
       'cpfor' => 'WE',
       'note' => 'EWWE',
    )),
  )
```